# libusb_set_configuration returns LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY

Tags: libusb

Apple's iPhone has a configuration that sets up an interface for HID.
My goal is to connect to it and set HID reports to the endpoint on that interface.
The device I am using is an iPhone 6S.
My code iterates over all available configurations and their interfaces until it finds that HID interface (which is configuration 1 with interface 2).
Here is some diagnostic information about it:

```yaml
 Configuration #2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total length: 149   Interface count: 3
    Configuration value: 2
    Configuration index: 6
    Attributes: 0xc0
    Max. power: 250

    Interface #1

        Setting #1
            Interface number: 0
            Alternate setting: 0
            Endpoint count: 0
            Interface class: Audio
            Interface sub-class: Audio
            Interface protocol: 0
            Interface index: 0



    Interface #2

        Setting #1
            Interface number: 1
            Alternate setting: 0
            Endpoint count: 0
            Interface class: Audio
            Interface sub-class: Communcation
            Interface protocol: 0
            Interface index: 0


        Setting #2
            Interface number: 1
            Alternate setting: 1
            Endpoint count: 1
            Interface class: Audio
            Interface sub-class: Communcation
            Interface protocol: 0
            Interface index: 0


            Endpoint 00
                Endpoint Address: 0x81
                Attributes: 0x1
                Max. packetsize: 192
                Interval: 4
                Refresh: 0
                Sync. Address: 0


    Interface #3

        Setting #1
            Interface number: 2
            Alternate setting: 0
            Endpoint count: 1
            Interface class: Human Interface Device
            Interface sub-class: Interface Specific
            Interface protocol: 0
            Interface index: 0


            Endpoint 00
                Endpoint Address: 0x83
                Attributes: 0x3
                Max. packetsize: 64
                Interval: 1
                Refresh: 0
                Sync. Address: 0
```

Now when I try to set the interface:

```c
int err = libusb_set_configuration(handle, i);
```

I get a LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY.

How can I fix that?  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try detaching kernel driver on the specific interfacing you want to set configuration and then set the configuration. Also check that setAutoDetachKernelDriver(interface_no) is set to false before detaching kernel driver.